# Furnace Control board or Bad Thermostat - Dual Fuel System no longer works

Tags: hvac

I have a Goodman furnace paired with Trane XR 13 (4TWR3024A1000AA) in a dual fuel configuration with a Goodman gas furnace (GMS80453ANA) as my auxiliary heat. The system is managed by an Ecobee 4.

With the sudden drop in temperatures over the Thanksgiving holiday, I noticed that the fan was running, but the heat pump was not working. I switched it to Aux, and the furnace kicked in and provided heat as expected.

On Friday, I checked the condenser to see if something was wrong. After removing the service panel, I immediately noticed a dead snake stuck between the terminals of the run capacitor near the top of the condenser housing. I disconnected the power, removed the snake, and tested the start and run capacitors to confirm that the uF’s were within spec. The start capacitor was below spec, so I decided to replace it.

I set the thermostat to HEAT and heard a click in the condenser, but the fan and compressor failed to start. I disconnected the power and turned off the system at the thermostat, waited 10 minutes, and tried to turn the system on again. I got no click on the second attempt, and the condenser failed to start. The unit did start up with manual manipulation of the contactor. I checked the low voltage coil and noticed I was not getting 24-27VAC with the system calling for heat.

Since it’s cold now, I figured I would switch back to auxiliary heat and worry about the heat pump in the spring. I quickly discovered that the auxiliary heat no longer works after making the repairs in the condenser. When I set the Ecobee to Aux heat, I hear the furnace spin up and ignite, but the fan fails to start within the usual 15-30 seconds of startup. The furnace tries 1-2 times, but the fans fails start up. The odd thing is that the furnace does start immediately after each furnace cool down. I am not sure what is going on here. Is something wrong with my furnace, thermostat, heat pump, or a combination thereof? The furnace has always operated even with the heat pump breaker off. Now neither system works. The only thing that the heat pump and furnace have in common is the Ecobee and the furnace control board. Could my Ecobee be the problem?

Current Situation:
When set to cool, the furnace fan comes on immediately, but the condenser fails to start.

When set to heat, the furnace fan comes on immediately, but the condenser fails to start.

When set to AUX, the furnace goes through its normal start up sequence, but the fan fails to start. The fan comes on immediately once the furnace ignition cycle stops and it enters cool down.

The FAN comes manually if selected within the Ecobee.

The Goodman Furnace LED indicator is solid RED

I have confirmed 26 VAC on the LV transformer.

I see no breaks in the LV cabling to the unit outside.

Comment: How old are the units?

Comment: Are you getting 24-27V from W to C at the furnace?  Also, is the control board throwing any codes?

Comment: This is a semi-complex situation because there are so many pieces. You can test the furnace with a jumper wire at its control board. Jumper R to G and verify the main blower starts reliably. Then jumper R to W and verify the inducer, burner, and blower start normally. No need to disconnect the existing control wires to test this. If the control terminals are inside the blower compartment you'll have to extend wires out of that compartment or bypass the compartment safety switch for the test.